# module_main.c:43: error: invalid use of undefined type ‘struct nf_hook_ops’

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, network-protocols, ubuntu-10.04

I am creating a Manet using the protocol ARAN. To install the protocol I'm using [this manual](http://prisms.cs.umass.edu/arand/install.php), but the first step, the creation of trace_route, I received errors such as:

```
module_main.c:43: error: invalid use of undefined type ‘struct nf_hook_ops’
module_main.c:45:'KERNEL_INFO' undeclared (first use in this function)
```

I searched the web and found out that the problem is in the netfilter, but I do not find the solution ...

P.S. I am using Ubuntu 10.04 LTS Kernel 2.6.33 recompiled

Comment: @Peppe_Cook Can you post the code of module_main.c up to line 45?

Comment: now the errors are these....

module_main.c:39: error: ‘KERN_INFO’ undeclared (first use in this function)
module_main.c:39: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
module_main.c:39: error: for each function it appears in.)
module_main.c:39: error: expected ‘)’ before string constant
module_main.c:43: error: invalid use of undefined type ‘struct nf_hook_ops’
module_main.c:44: error: invalid use of undefined type ‘struct nf_hook_ops’
module_main.c:45: error: invalid use of undefined type ‘struct nf_hook_ops’

Comment: #include "module_main.h"
#include "route_cache.h"
#include "utils.h"

extern struct route_cache_entry *route_cache;

/* entries for our different PROC files */
/* /proc/asl/route_check */
static struct proc_dir_entry *asl_dir, *route_check;

/* for the netfilter hooks */
struct nf_hook_ops filter;

int init_module(void)
{
    int result;

    printk(KERN_INFO "Adhoc Support Framework : Route_check module: Starting up\n");

    filter.list.next = NULL;
    filter.list.prev = NULL;
    filter.hook = input_handler;
    filter.pf = PF_INET; // IPv4
    filter.hooknum = NF_IP_POST_ROUTING;

Comment: @Peppe_Cook Try putting these toward the top of your module_main.c: #include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>

Comment: @PeterL. i tryed but without results...

Comment: @Peppe_Cook There is a book called Linux Device Drivers.  They have a very simple 'hello world' device driver to build.  You should consider downloading it and building it (it is free, AFAIK), or at least code it up to verify your build environment.  KERN_INFO is one of the basic defines in Linux drivers.  It should be picked up via one of the other headers.

Comment: Yes, I know this book, I read part of it last week, but it is not the solution errors. Searching the net I found that the errors in question are in File NETFILTER.h especially (the invalid use of undefined type 'struct nf_hook_ops' )  I think it's a structure that is missing in File

Comment: @PeterL. The error refers to `KERNEL_INFO`, a different symbol than `KERN_INFO` (in fact `KERNEL_INFO` isn't in the Linux kernel at all).

Comment: @VilhelmGray That must be a typo in the example.  My guess is that if it is changed to KERN_INFO then all will compile.

Comment: @PeterL. Oh I see what you mean now, I overlooked code in the comments.

Comment: @PeppeCook How are you compiling this code? I suspect that you are not passing the path to your kernel headers correctly to your compiler.

Comment: @Vilhem Gray Now i compile using gcc -3O -Wall -DMODULE -D_KERNEL_ -DLINUX -I/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.33.1/include/linux/ -c module_main -o module_main-o if i prove to compile with another string i have more errors like asm/FILENAME.h No such FILE or Directory....

Comment: in order to compile the code, I have used many paths in various kernels and my conclusions are that the types of errors are two or (asm / filename.h: Error No such file) or (directory or 'struct nf_hook_ops') .. . they do not appear together but alternate.